# Can we Call Two diiferent methods in Transaction scope in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, transactionscope, rollback

Hello i am new to Transaction Scope in C#. i have two insert queries one belongs to UserAccountCreation where LoginCredentials are stored and another is Inserting Employee details with respective UserAccountID in Employee table as foreign key.

I have two different methods written to insert in UserAccount Table and after inserting into UserAccount the UserAccountID is feteched and Inserted into Employee table. 
Situation is When UserAccount Creation succeeds and Employee Creation fails, then it must ROLLBACK. So, i would like to know whether we can use Transaction scope and in between call these two Insert Methods? and can we rollback these methods which have called in this scope if error occurs.
Sample Code:

```
private void CreateEmp()
{
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
    try
    {
        CreateUserAccount();
        CreateEmployee();
        scope.Complete();
    } 
    catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
        {

    }
  }
}
```

Help Appreciated!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call as many functions as you want in the transaction scope.
If you want two methods can handle their own connections (open/use/close/dispose), yet they will silently become part of the ambient transaction without us having to pass anything in.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgesD for replying! I would like to know if Method one success and method two fails will it rollback the Method1?

Comment: Yes, if dispose is called before scope.Complete() the TransactionScope will tell the connections to rollback their transactions.

Comment: i am not getting you! Do you mean i should call scope.Dispose(); before scope.Complete(); line?

Comment: I just mean that if the scope.complete is not called then the Transactionscope well rollback the transaction. I think you should put the "try ... catch" outside of the using

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) should answer your question. To shortcut just read the comments in the code example

Comment: will the abouve code work..as i mentioned or shall i do some changes..if yes plz specify...or Edit my code...!

Comment: The Example you have given should work, and as stated in other answers if either of the 2 methods before your call to scope.Complete() throws an error, the transaction would make a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is why we use transaction scope.

Comment: will the above code work..as i mentioned or shall i do some changes..if yes plz specify...or Edit my code...!

Answer (score 0):

**Task at hand:** 
I need to insert a row in 4 tables when the user clicks on the 'Update' button.

**The following is working well for me:**

I added a variable to the class where the 4 update methods are and setting it to false if an exception in caught in any of the 4 methods. Calling `tran.Complete();` without this didn't work for me.

```
/* This variable is used to check if updating the scorecard succeeded. 
Set this variable to false in catch blocks of the 4 update methods. */

private bool bAllUpdated = true;
```

My update click method looks like this:

```
/* Showing the try-catch block only */
try
{
    using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
         UpdateMethod1();
         UpdateMethod2();
         UpdateMethod3();
         UpdateMethod4();

         if (bAllUpdated == true)
         {
             tran.Complete();
             lblSC_Success.Visible = true;
         }
         else
             throw new TransactionAbortedException();
    }
}

catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
      bAllUpdated = false;
      lblSCEditWarning.Text = "There was an error and your changes where NOT saved. " + ex.Message;
}
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{
    bAllUpdated = false;
    lblSCEditWarning.Text = "There was an error and your changes where NOT saved. " + ex.Message;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    bAllUpdated = false;
    lblSCEditWarning.Text = "There was an error and your changes where NOT saved. " + ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    // Clean up the temp tables
    // Refresh page
}
```

Comment: There is no rollback in your example.